# Show request in Camel route

Tags: integration, apache-camel, esb

Is there any way to log request from body in camel route?

```
<camel:log message="RequestType [${request.body.request}]" loggingLevel="INFO" />
```

Error in logs:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.language.simple.types.SimpleParserException: Unknown function: request.body.request
```

This is working part, but dunno how to get into field :

```
        <camel:log message="RequestType ${in.body}" loggingLevel="INFO" />
        <camel:log message="RequestType2 [${body}]" loggingLevel="INFO" />
```

Request field for sure it's not empty becaue later I'm checking it:

```
<camel:ognl>request.body.request instanceof ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
<camel:log message="RequestType [${body.request}]" loggingLevel="INFO" />
```

The camel:log is using the simple language which you can read more about here: http://camel.apache.org/simple

Comment: ERROR [Camel (ccgwContext) thread #3 - Threads] coreV2:145 - Unexpected exception occurred while processing coure route v2.0 [Failed to invoke method: .request on null due to: org.apache.camel.language.bean.RuntimeBeanExpressionException: Failed 
to invoke method: request on null 

It's strange cause after a moment I'm using this and it's working:
                        <camel:ognl>request.body.request instanceof pl.gtp.vas.ccgw.model.transport.ChargeRequest</camel:ognl>

Comment: what does it say if you log ${body} and ${body.class}?

Comment: It works, I will receive all fields which are inside body. Also request!

Comment: But still I cannot receive only one field like a body.request... =/ dunno why

Comment: Ok, probably it was because I had two the same named types on body... It wasn't camel mistake. Thanks for help!